# Chartjs - button in legend to toggle all datasets show/hide

Tags: chart.js

Is there way to toggle display/hide all datasets in a chart at once?

I'm working on a chart that will have about 30 datasets so that different sets of data can be easily compared... but it's a hassle to deselect 28 in order to just see two. Or to go from 2 to then select 25 to view.

I'd like to find some way to show all/hide all... I wonder if creating the legend via a callback would be required... and if so, how to do it (I haven't yet figured out how to use callbacks).

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Scott

Comment: Check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49249902/select-all-and-unselect-option-for-chart-js/49252102#49252102

Comment: Thanks @beaver! That's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: So, please, vote up my answer there ;-)

Comment: @beaver point your link as an answer or as duplicate, its really more visible!